# Osgi ConfigurationAdmin delay in activating Component

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

I have a service that requires a configuration

```
@Component(service=InstrumenterService.class ,configurationPid = "InstrumenterService", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)
public class InstrumenterService
```

This service is referenced inside another service :

```
@Component(service = SampleService.class, scope = ServiceScope.PROTOTYPE)
public class SampleService {

    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL, scope = ReferenceScope.PROTOTYPE_REQUIRED, policyOption = ReferencePolicyOption.GREEDY)
    InstrumenterService coverageInstrumenter;

    public boolean hasInstrumenter() {
        if(coverageInstrumenter == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This SampleService is used inside a Main class hooked to the main osgi thread.
I'm using ComponentServiceObjects as I want to create on demand SampleServices.

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = "main.thread=true")
public class Main implements Runnable {

    @Reference
    ConfigurationAdmin cfgAdm;

    @Reference(scope = ReferenceScope.PROTOTYPE_REQUIRED)
    private ComponentServiceObjects<SampleService> sampleServices;

    public void run() {
        if (cfgAdm != null) {
            Configuration configuration;
            try {
                configuration = cfgAdm.getConfiguration("InstrumenterService", "?");
                Hashtable<String, Object> props = new Hashtable<>();
                props.put("some_prop", "some_value");
                configuration.update(props);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        SampleService servicess = sampleServices.getService();
        System.out.println(servicess.hasInstrumenter());
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the configuration set by the ConfigurationAdmin is not visible in the InstrumenterService unless I put a Thread.sleep(500); command after calling the configuration.update.

I'm not really confortable using a Thread.sleep command to ensure the configuration update is visible.
Is there an API to check that the configuration has been updated and is available to use ?

Thanks to Neil I was able to find a workable solution.
I used a ServiceTracker after the configuration was set to wait for the service:

```
        BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getBundleContext();
    ServiceTracker serviceTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, InstrumenterService.class.getName(), null);

    serviceTracker.open();
    try {
        serviceTracker.waitForService(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    serviceTracker.close();
```

The reason I needed ConfigurationAdmin in the first place is because there is an interface IInstrumenter which can be implemented by many different classes.
The name of this instrumenter is set in the ConfigurationAdmin and then further on in other services the required instrumeter service is fetch "automagically".

This way any number of instrumenter could be added to the application and only the name of the instrumeter needs to be known in order for it to be used.

I want to mention also that with OSGI we managed to split our monolith legacy application in more modules (~15) and they do not depend directly on each other but use an API layer.

Thanks again for the good job you are doing with OSGI.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to wait for the configuration to update?

Comment: if I do not wait for the configuration update I will get a null reference for  InstrumenterService coverageInstrumenter (because ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)  inside the SampleService class. If I do wait then the covergeInstrumenter service is no longer null.

Comment: Sorry I phrased my question wrongly. Why do you need to get the instance of the service in the same method where you set the configuration?

Comment: I do not necessarily need it in the same method. This is a simplified example capturing the problem. I the real application I do not call them from the same method, but I do have a main method hooked on main.thread=true". In the real application this problem happens sporadically, as there is considerably more processing done between setting the configuration and creating the services that needs the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, this code is not exactly realistic. In production code there is not normally a requirement to update a configuration record and then immediately obtain a service published by a component. This is because any such code makes too many assumptions about the effect of the configuration update.

A call to `getServiceReference` and `getService` returns only a snapshot of the service registry state at a particular instant. It is inherently unreliable to call `getService` expecting it to return a value.

In reality, we always use a pattern where we react to being notified of the existence of the service. This can be done in various ways, including `ServiceListener` and `ServiceTracker`, but the simplest is to write a component with a reference, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Reference
    SampleService service;

    public void doSomething() {
        println(service.hasInstrumenter());
    }
}
```

This component has a mandatory reference to `SampleService` and will only be activated only when an instance of `SampleService` is available.

Comment: I think the problem is that the main application is actually starting in a single main thread which sets the configuration and reference services. For most of the application I used DS (which I like very much btw). All the services are resolved nicely except those that use ConfigurationAdmin. I am using ConfigurationAdmin to set a property which will then automagically activate only the right InstrumenterService class (from many implementing the same interface). I guess I will have to use a pattern that reacts to ConfigurationAdmin changes. Thank you for your answer and I like osgi very much.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you don't want to refactor to a DS component then you can write your single method to wait for the service to appear, e.g. using `ServiceTracker.waitForService()`. Though as I hinted in my answer above, I think this assumes too much knowledge about the downstream effects of making the configuration change, which creates a hidden dependency.